# Update record in ServiceNow by passing JSON object in the URL

Tags: json, servicenow

I am trying to update a record in a ServiceNow instance (running Calgary) using the [JSON Web Service](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=JSON_Web_Service), but unfortunately it is not happening.

I am able to `insert` the record but the `update` operation doesn't happen.

The call in the Developer tools of chrome (Network section) looks good (could see the url and JSON object bound with data)

Here's the code snippet with the URL I'm testing:

```
var url = 'https://<instance name>.service-now.com/u_test_employee.do?JSON&sysparm_query=u_number=EMP0001102&‌​sysparm_action=update'
var responsePromise = $http.post(url, dataObj, {});
```

Any ideas or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing a version that has JSONv2 (Dublin release or above)?
It might help to see the URL and JSON payload you're sending

Comment: Also... how are you consuming the JSON processor? Using a tool, or just executing in browser console?

Comment: i am on calgary and passing JSON object not the v2 version. 
code snippet which i am using. 

var responsePromise = $http.post('https://<instance name>.service-now.com/u_test_employee.do?JSON&sysparm_query=u_number=EMP0001102&sysparm_action=update', dataObj, {});

URL-> https://<instance name>.service-now.com/u_test_employee.do?JSON&sysparm_query=u_number=EMP0001102&sysparm_action=update
 
JSON object binded in dataObj variable. could see the values in property.

Comment: What are you posting as `dataObj`? What was actually passed where you have the empty object `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause for failure of update operation might be missing ACLs. The table which you are trying to update need to have table level write ACL otherwise by default no write (update) operations are allowed